# How can I make use of a Genius HiSketch 1212 serial-port drawing tablet on a modern PC?

Tags: serial, driver, old-hardware-adaptation, input-devices, virtual-machine

I have a friend that still uses Windows 98 because of a drawing tablet (Genius HiSketch 1212) that he is not able to install in modern systems. He has Windows 98 installed in an old PC that's always giving him problems. I suggested to him to install VMware on his Windows 10 PC and install Windows 98 inside a virtual machine. Installation of Windows 98 was successful, but we are having trouble with the driver for the tablet.

To connect the tablet, we are using a USB-serial adapter (USB-RS232) connected to the Windows 10 PC. I'm going to help him one of these days.

My question is, can I migrate the driver for the tablet from the old PC to the virtual machine installation?

The serial port is recognized by Windows 10 as a serial port (like, COM3 for example. I'm not sure about the number). Then, in the configuration of the virtual machine in VMware, I set up a serial port and assigned the COM3 of Windows 10 to the new virtual serial port (COM1 in Windows 98). So the serial port in Windows 98 is recognized the same as a physical serial port would be. There's no clues about any USB-serial or USB device connected (from inside de virtual machine).

Here are some screenshots to show exactly what I did in my friend's computer. Those were made on my computer, because I'm not at his home now, but everything is the same regarding device configuration.

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]
[image: Step 3]
[image: Step 4]

Comment: I would guess the driver expects the tablet to be connected to a motherboard-driven serial port, not a USB-encapsulated one, so you’d have to connect the VM’s serial port to the USB serial device. With QEMU, that’s just `-serial /dev/ttyUSB0`. Though personally, I’d at least take a stab at reverse-engineering the tablet protocol and writing my own driver.

Comment: This sounds more like a question about Windows 10 capabilities than about any old system. But even then it may need way more information for a useful answer. Starting by all components involved, best including what driver model the driver is made to, as only if that model is supported by Win10, a port would be hasslefree.

Comment: You still have not provided the model number of the tablet device. Voting to close for now, though I will vote to reopen if you provide that, as the question is otherwise perfectly topical; I do not subscribe to the ‘every single transistor must be made in the 1980s or it’s off-topic’ ideology.

Comment: Unless this is a very expensive digitizer, or the friend is especially low on money, I can't help thinking it's surely more practical to replace it with a modern device.   There's nothing wrong with using old hardware for the fun -- this is the retrocomputing forum after all -- but the way the post reads, it's about getting the digitizer to work, and the retrocomputing aspect is simply a means to that end.

Comment: It looks as if you assigned COM1 of the host to the single serial port of the guest, not COM3. The name in the guest will depend on the OS installed, for example a Linux will not use the name "COM1".

Comment: Now that we have the model, someone managed to get it working in Ubuntu: <https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1784259>.

Comment: //This sounds more like a question about Windows 10 capabilities than about any old system.//  If no Windows 10 driver exists, using a small embedded microcontroller devkit to build an interface to make the tablet behave as a USB-HID device may be easier than writing a Windows 10 driver, and the portions of the project dealing with how to decode information from the tablet would seem to fall squarely within retrocomputing territory.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I still didn't found the solution to my problem.
Furthermore, I writing a new question, because the problem now has changed - I managed to install the driver on a Windows 98 (not VM) installation. Thanks

Comment: The drawing pad has DIP switches for configuration. It should support also mouse mode using Microsoft or Mouse Systems protocol. So in mouse mode, it should work in Win 10 too using USB to serial adapter.

Answer (score 5):

I cannot say much about Windows, but this particular tablet model has reportedly been successfully made to run with Linux, based on this [Ubuntu forums post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1784259&s=c68275e385155fabc89bf38ea28e3da5&p=10991851#post10991851).

The solution involves launching the [`inputattach`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/inputattach) utility in order to register the serial port as an input device within the evdev subsystem and translate its event reporting protocol into one digestible by evdev clients (which is usually just the X11 server or Wayland compositor, in turn forwarding input events to applications).  The command to run should look something like this:

```
inputattach -mtouch /dev/ttyUSB0
```

with `/dev/ttyUSB0` replaced by the character device corresponding to the serial port (whether motherboard-driven or a USB/RS-232 adapter; the example assumes the latter).  This should make the tablet work in native tablet mode; the device also has a mouse emulation mode, in which the `-mtouch` option ought to be replaced by (probably) `-bare`, `-ms3` or `-msc`.

This command has to be run as root (or at least with sufficient privileges to access the serial port and evdev devices) each time the tablet is connected via the serial port.  A good way to automate this would be to write a systemd service whose launch is triggered by a udev rule in turn triggered by the device being connected, but I am afraid describing how to set this up may turn out pretty long-winded, and borderline out-of-scope for this site.