# How can I install a driver for a digitizing tablet Genius HiSketch 1212 in a VMWare virtual machine running Windows 98SE?

Tags: windows-98, driver, rs232

I posted a question some time ago - [How can I make use of a Genius HiSketch 1212 serial-port drawing tablet on a modern PC?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/23971/how-can-i-make-use-of-a-genius-hisketch-1212-serial-port-drawing-tablet-on-a-mod) - and I didn't found the solution, but the scenario now has changed. This is why I'm posting a new question.

My goal is to install a VMware virtual machine running Windows 98 SE in a Windows 7 / 10 modern computer, and in the virtual machine with Win 98 install a driver to be able to use a Genius HiSketch 1212 serial port (RS232) drawing tablet. The tablet has a serial port (RS232) interface and my computer (Mobo Gigabyte GA-H81M-S2PH, CPU Intel Pentium G3220, 16GB DIMM DDR3)("TACENS" from now on) has the serial connector (RS232) in the back panel.

Previously, I managed to install Windows 98 SE on a COMPAQ PRESARIO - S5490ES (this is an old computer) - and I successfully installed the driver for the drawing tablet Genius HiSketch 1212, using the physical serial port on the back panel of this COMPAQ - and it finally worked - I can use the tablet on it.

Now, the next step (The final step) is to install a virtual machine with VMWare in my TACENS and install Windows 98SE, and then add a Serial port to the VM. I have two COM ports, and I have tried a serial port monitoring application to see what port of them corresponds to the tablet. I have seen that COM2 port is not responding, but COM1 is showing some strange characters when I move the pencil. So, in VMWare, I added the COM1 port to the virtual machine. I installed the COM port driver in Windows 98, and after the drawing tablet driver, but once the driver is installed and I move the pencil, nothing happens.

Before, when I asked the previous question, I was trying to connect the tablet to a Windows 10 laptop with an adapter USB/RS232, and I didn't even know how to install the driver for the tablet in Windows 98. So I was lost, not knowing whether the problem was due to the USB adapter, or the drivers I was trying to install. Now, I have managed to install the driver in a computer (COMPAQ PRESARIO, previously mentioned), via the built-in RS232 connector in the back panel. So I thought, if I have a modern computer that has the RS232 port, it would be easy to install a virtual machine and add the physical port (not USB) to inside the virtual machine (using VMWAre). Now my problem is I don't know if the no-functioning of the tablet is due to VMWare, or some silly error, because in my opinion, it should normally work. What mistake did I make? I would appreciate your help. Also I can post any information you need, if you explain to me where to get it.

Let me show you some screenshots

The serial port monitoring application

[image]

The activity log files

[image]

The content of the log files in Notepad++

[image]

[image]

The configuration of the Windows 98 VM in VMWare

[image]

Now I'm adding some photos and screenshots answering @user3840170

First, the com port configuration in the COMPAQ old computer.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, the TACENS com port configuration

[image]

[image]

[image]
Then I saw the com port config in COMPAQ, and the flow control was Xon/Xoff, and in TACENS it was set to "none", so I thought maybe setting the same on my TACENS would fix the problem. So I changed it.

[image]

Now, the VMWare configuration and the virtual machine with Win 98 Com port config

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now I want to show you all how's the tablet and the original cables installation

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have been testing the tablet in a Ubuntu virtual machine (same VMWare that the original one), as pointed by @user3840170 in the linked question - [Previous question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/23971/how-can-i-make-use-of-a-genius-hisketch-1212-serial-port-drawing-tablet-on-a-mod)

To do this, I had to set two COM ports inside the virtual machine, because I don't know which of them is the correct one.

[image]

[image]

then I executed the command

```
inputattach -mtouch /dev/ttyS0
```

and the variants, as shown below

[image]

I downloaded a serial port debugging tool from[virtual-serial-port.org](https://www.virtual-serial-port.org) and made a screenshot of the COM2 port activity as I moved the pencil.

[image]

I want to upload a log file, but I can't, so I'm sharing the file with my google drive - [COM port debugging](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1smVr6J7t8J1AgVdqvenDA7UUflKyfeji/view?usp=sharing).
Note that (I think, not sure) you have to use the virtual-serial-port.org software to open this log file.

For clarification:
There are 3 physical computers in my scenario. First, the previously mentioned TACENS (Windows 7). It has VMWare Workstation 12 and in this VMWare I have mentioned 2 virtual machines: one with Windows 98 SE and other with Ubuntu Desktop. In the Windows 98 virtual machine I was trying to setup the serial connection and the tablet driver. After, in the Ubuntu Desktop virtual machine, I tried some commands to get the tablet to work (unsuccessfully), as suggested by @user3840170 . After I did some serial port monitoring.
The second physical computer, previously mentioned as COMPAQ, is the one with Windows 98 SE installed, where I mentioned that the tablet is working correctly.
The third is called, for example, let's say, HPNEW. I didn't yet mentioned it but I have installed Windows 7 and I'm planning to try with virtual machines too.

Here there are some photos of the tablet.

[image]

[image]

I have been notified about another post that would possibly answer my question.
it is [How can I make use of a Genius HiSketch 1212 serial-port drawing tablet on a modern PC?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/23971/how-can-i-make-use-of-a-genius-hisketch-1212-serial-port-drawing-tablet-on-a-mod). As I said before, I posted this question myself, but now the scenario has changed - now I'm trying to use a physical real RS232 serial port, and in the previous post I was using an USB/serial port adapter. Also the answers to my previous question didn't resolve my problem. I also want to say sorry because in the previous question some people tried to help me but I was too busy and I didn't have the time to reply to their comments.

Comment: **The troubleshooting has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137428/discussion-on-question-by-borhacker-how-can-i-install-a-driver-for-a-digitizing)**, since that's a better place for it. Comments aren't well-suited for discussion.